# Laravel 4 - Package or "modules"?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm starting to work with Laravel 4, it seems to be a great choice, anyway before coding my first project i'd like to understand if my usual approach could be ok with laravel.

Usually i keep triad for backend and frontend separated under a /modules folder, like this:

```
/modules
       /backend
               /config
               /controllers
               /models
               /migrations
               /ecc..
       /frontend (and so on...)
```

With laravel i'm not really sure how to manage this. I'm trying with packages, but the `php artisan workbench me/mypackage --resources` don't build the entire folder structure... where to put controllers and models, and how to setup routes?

Then i found this [link](http://creolab.hr/2013/05/modules-in-laravel-4/) to enable modules-like system. So, what's the approach i should follow for keeping things in the laravel way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, let's begin...

First, I created `Andreyco\Cart` package using Artisan.
Package and it's structure

```
|workbench
|-andreyco
|---cart
|-----public
|-----src
|-------Andreyco
|---------Cart
|-------config
|-------lang
|-------migrations
|-------views
|-----tests
|-----vendor
```

In the answers, I will use this exact package as example.

Imagine, that folder `workbench/andreyco/cart/src` is the application folder. If you do, you should know the most of the answers. (Actually App is package as well)

**Q:** *how to setup routes*
**A:** Create the file -> `workbench/andreyco/cart/src/routes.php`. This is done.

**Q:** *where to put controllers and models*
**A:** Just create `controllers` and `models` folder there.
So the `TestController` would be located at `workbench/andreyco/cart/src/controllers/TestController.php` file. Very same with models.
Directory tree would look like this

```
|workbench
|-andreyco
|---cart
|-----public
|-----src
|-------Andreyco
|---------Cart
|-------config
|-------controlers
|-------lang
|-------migrations
|-------models
|-------views
|-----tests
|-----vendor
```

I created the `routes.php`, `TestController.php` and the `TestModel.php`

```
// workbench/andreyco/cart/src/routes.php
<?php

Route::get('test', 'Andreyco\\Cart\\Controllers\\TestController@index');



// workbench/andreyco/cart/src/controllers/TestController.php
<?php namespace Andreyco\Cart\Controllers;

use Andreyco\Cart\Models\TestModel;

class TestController extends \BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return TestModel::printCurrentLocation(__DIR__);
    }
}



// workbench/andreyco/cart/src/models/TestModel.php
<?php namespace Andreyco\Cart\Models;

class TestModel extends \Eloquent
{
    public static function printCurrentLocation($location)
    {
        return "Testing package controller, script is located at: {$location}";
    }
}
```

As you can see, I used namespaces, so you should.
Namespaces make your life a lot of easier.

**Important:** after creating those files, you need to update `composer.json` file, so that classes could be autoloaded

```
// composer.json
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
        "workbench/andreyco/cart/src/controllers",
        "workbench/andreyco/cart/src/models"
    ]
},
```

After this, dump the changes using `composer dump-autoload -o` command.

**Q:** *So, what's the approach i should follow for keeping things in the laravel way?*
**A:** In my opinion, you should stick to packages. At least, I would. That's the way Laravel was designed to work.

I hope this helps you, good luck!

**Edit**
Views are not problem here. They work just like in main app package.

```
// workbench/cart/src/view/foldername/viewname.blade.php

<h1>Testing view file.</h1>
{{ "Blade" }} syntax is parsed as well, no problem here.
```

Returning view from package's controller is pretty simple

```
public function index()
    {
        return \View::make('cart::foldername.viewname');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you Andrej. That was really helpful! So, routes must be namespaced, but why the double slash?

Comment: Double backslash is used to escape `\` character. Someone correct me, if I'm wrong. Laravel translates this into namespace correctly

Comment: Apparently I forgot to escape the ` \ ` character in previous comment.

Comment: Ok got it. Seems that routes, if placed inside app/routes.php works without double backslash, anyway now i'm having another doubt: how i use partials view into the package's master template? I've tried namespacing like this @include('backend::_partials.nav') or this @include('backend::_partials/nav') but still not working.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I updated the answer with info how to return View object. To answer question about controllers & namespaces: you can use namespaced controllers in `app/routes.php` as well. You do not have to use namespaces at packages (or app) at all - it's up to you, but namespaces can make your live easier.

Comment: @Andreyco - Thanks, this is very useful! @Luciano - You dont namespace your views. You just put them in folders. When you want to include a view, you can just do `@include(aaaa.bbbb.cccc.view)` This would refer to the following directory structure `views/aaaa/bbbb/cccc/view.blade.php` Hope this helps

Comment: Oh, and from within a package, the view can be referred to by `packagename::viewfolder.viewname`