# Laravel controllers and routes in packages?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, package, laravel-routing

I'm having trouble registering controllers to routes in my package.

As far as I understand from the official documentation I just need to simply prefix it and use my namespace though I always get the error of xyzclass not found.

Anyone could explain to me how can I make this work?

`-- Vendor
    -- Package
        |-- composer.json
        |-- composer.lock
        |-- public
        |-- src
        |   |-- Vendor
        |   |   -- Package
        |   |       -- PackageServiceProvider.php
        |   |-- config
        |   |-- controllers
        |   |   -- MyController.php
        |   |-- lang
        |   |-- migrations
        |   |-- routes.php
        |    -- views
        |-- tests`

I loaded my routes.php in my serviceprovider file.
I created and index function in MyController.php and assigned it in my routes.php.

```
Route::contorller('myctrl', 'Vendor\Package\MyController');
```

And in theory I should be able to access mydomain.com/myctrl and it should give me back
what I defined in MyController's index function. But in reality I get an error saying  Class Vendor\Package\MyController does not exists. Any advice or help how should this work or how it's working?

Answer (score 1):

Guess I'm dumb, forgot some little details.
I should use a proper namespace next time, and adding the controllers folder to my composer.json helped too.

I found a nice and detailed description on how to do this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18137352/1397967

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::contorller('myctrl', 'MyController');
```

This is linked to `src/controllers/` not to `vendor`

Comment: try composer dump-autoload

Comment: Same.

ReflectionException Class MyController does not exist